# Compute a certain $P(A_n i.o.)$

Tags: probability-theory, probability-limit-theorems

Let $p\in(0,1)$. For each $n\in\mathbb{N}$, consider a random variable $X_n$, $X_n$ has binomial distribution with parameters $n$ and $p$. The $X_n$ are independent. Compute, for each $\epsilon>0$

### \begin{equation}
\displaystyle \mathrm{P}(\limsup_{n\longrightarrow \infty} X_n\geq n^{1-\epsilon})
\end{equation}

My attempt:

1. First, I think in this property. For each event $A_n$
   \begin{equation}
   \displaystyle \mathrm{P}(\limsup A_n)\geq  \limsup\mathrm{P}( A_n)
   \end{equation}
   From my point of view, this is useful only if $\limsup_{n\longrightarrow \infty}\mathrm{P}( X_n\geq n^{1-\epsilon})=1$. But I don't know how to prove it.

2.(I know this point gives a total different result). I tried to use The First Borel-Cantelli Lemma, i.e., if $\sum_{n=1}^\infty P(A_n)<\infty\Rightarrow P(A_n i.o.)=0$. But I don't know how to define the summands such that the series converges.
My problem is I don't know how to control $n^{1-\epsilon}$, because all the exercises I've done before $n^{1-\epsilon}$ is replaced by only one variable, namely, $\epsilon$, the bound is fixed, but in this case the lower bound is changing.

Comment: Are the $X_n$s independent?

Comment: Yes, my mistake. I'll edit it, right now.

Comment: By the law of large numbers $X_n/n\approx p\gg n^{-\epsilon}$ when $n$ is large hence one can guess that indeed $X_n\ge n^{1-\epsilon}$ infinitely often. Thus, the task is to prove that $P(\liminf C_n)=0$ with $C_n=(X_n\le n^{1-\epsilon})$. By Borel-Cantelli, it suffices to show that the series $\sum P(C_n)$ converges. Can you estimate $P(C_n)$ efficiently enough to deduce this? (Note that the independence of the sequence $(X_n)$ is not needed.)